# VueJS - how build dynamic values, using the mustaches?

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, concatenation, mustache

In data, I have 2 arrays.
In the template, I want to use value of a special key of an array, to target the second array.

```
<template>
  <table>
    <tr v-for="sa in mySecondArray">
      <td v-for="fa in myFirstArray">
         {{ ??? }}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</template>

// ...
data() {
  myFirstArray: [
  {
    a: "KeyOne",
    b: "we don't care",
    c: "we don't care",
  },
  {
    a: "KeyTwo",
    b: "we don't care",
    c: "we don't care",
  },
  ],
  mySecondArray: [
  {
    KeyOne: "foo",
    KeyTwo: "bar"
  },
  {
    KeyOne: "hello",
    KeyTwo: "world"
  },
  ],
```

In this exemple, I want to display

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>foo</td>
      <td>hello</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bar</td>
      <td>world</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I tried :

```
<tr v-for="sa in mySecondArray">
  <td v-for="fa in myFirstArray">
    {{ sa + fa.a }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

in this case it displays [object Object].

I tried :

```
<tr v-for="sa in mySecondArray">
  <td v-for="fa in myFirstArray">
    {{ sa.concat('.',fa.a) }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

in this case console says: "sa.concat is not a function".
I also tried with quotes, but it just concats the strings: "sa.KeyOne".
How to make this final string used as a target and not just a string ?

Comment: This is not work? `{{ sa }} {{ fa.a }}`

Comment: `{{ sa }} {{ fa.a }}` displays all the "sa" object, followed by the good name of the column I want to target to, like that:
{KeyOne: "foo",KeyTwo: "bar"}KeyOne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to get your result,

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    firstArray: [{
        a: "KeyOne",
        b: "we don't care",
        c: "we don't care",
    },
    {
        a: "KeyTwo",
        b: "we don't care",
        c: "we don't care",
    }],
    secondArray: [
    {
        KeyOne: "foo",
        KeyTwo: "bar"
    },
    {
        KeyOne: "hello",
        KeyTwo: "world"
    },
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>head1</th>
      <th>head2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="(sa1, index1) in secondArray" >
         <td v-for="(sa2, index2) in secondArray">
           {{secondArray[index2][firstArray[index1].a]}}
         </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Hope this solves your problem!